# How to look up values in different columns, then take the average

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet of ratings for different categories (overall, call, service, person) and with each category is a rating from 1-5. Below is an example of how it looks:

[image: Here's an example of the layout]

I am trying to write a formula that will lookup the rating based on category, and take the average of all the ratings. I took a look at VLOOKUP, but I got confused.

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel has a handy AVERAGEIF() function for this.

[image]

This formula in D2, filled down, does what you need:

`=AVERAGEIF(A$2:A$8,C2,B$2:B$8)`

How it works:

AVERAGEIF(range, criteria, [average_range])

Where the range A2:A8 equals C2, the formula calculates and returns the average of the corresponding cells from B2:B8.  As it's filled down, it does the same for the categories specified in C3 and C4.

Comment: Wow, that's super simple! Thanks a lot, I'm very new to excel and I was struggling with this problem.

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to SU.